# Emails not sending - a good way to fix this?

Tags: wordpress, email, smtp, mailgun

I work for an advertising agency working with several clients who we are building and managing wordpress websites for. One issue that arises every time with a new install, is the issue with emails not sending/receiving. We usually solve this by installing an SMTP plugin and set it up using the clients Office 365 email account or whatever provider they have.

The problem is that this is a little time consuming, as well as some of our clients either don´t want to give away their account information/they don't know their account information/they change passwords and forms stop working.

We need a stable email solution that we can use on a wide spectrum of client pages, and that we hopefully don´t need to set up every time we make a new webpage.  Does anyone have any solutions/suggestions for this?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Before I get into the recommendation, WordPress should use your servers default sendmail configuration so it’s possible something is misconfigured here as it should work out of the box.

But if you want something a little more bulletproof I recommend SendGrid. 
One of the problems with all your sites using the same mail server is if one is blacklisted for something the others go down. With SendGrid, which is free for 10k send a month I think, you can issue an api key for each site and if one has an issue it you can easily identify it in SendGrid.

I have setup dozens of API Keys and the plug-in. It’s fast and simple and takes about 5 minutes in total. They have great delivery, detailed reports and are cheap even if you need a lot of sends. 
You can Signup for an account and use the SendGrid plugin from the Wordpress repository.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I looked into SendGrid and it seems interesting! =) Might be an option in the future.